# Pillow cropping gif gives invalid dimensions error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to crop a gif to a square. I am using `pillow`. The square needs to be the center of the image.[image]
Like shown in the image above. I want the same thing to happen when the image height is greater than the width.
My current code is as following. It works fine with images but not with gifs.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

im = Image.open('950_kb.gif')

width, height = im.size

print(im.size)

if width != height:
  if width > height:
    left = (width - height) / 2
    top = 0
    width = (width + height) / 2
    height = height
  else:
    left = 0
    top = (height - width) / 2
    width = width
    height= (height + width) / 2

  print((left, top, width, height))

  if getattr(im, "is_animated", False):
    frames = []

    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
      frames.append(frame.crop((left, top, width, height)))

    im.save('test.webp', format="webp", save_all=True, append_images=list(frames), loop=0)
  else:
    im = im.crop((left, top, width, height))

    im.save('test.webp', format="webp")
```

When using a gif it gives the following error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    im.save('test.webp', format="webp", save_all=True, append_images=list(frames), loop=0)
  File "/home/runner/PythonTheBasics/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2320, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/runner/PythonTheBasics/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py", line 278, in _save_all
    enc.add(
RuntimeError: ERROR adding frame: Invalid frame dimensions.
```

The original file dimensions:

```py
(498, 276)
```

The calculated `left, top, width, height` variables.

```py
(111.0, 0, 276, 276)
```

Here is also the gif used that raised this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the way the new frames were getting saved. Where I used:

```py
im.save('test.webp', format="webp", save_all=True, append_images=list(frames), loop=0)
```

I should have been using:

```py
frames[0].save('test.webp', format="webp", save_all=True, append_images=list(frames), loop=0)
```

Issue and answer found by discord user [hsp#8591](https://discord.com/users/787351231332483102).